# should i uninstall useless software from my pc

Tags: testing, architecture

Guys I have some software in my pc which I didn't use atoll so should I Uninstall  all that software because it's taking space in c drive
is that software effecting my c drive ?or decreasing my pc efficiency ??

if no to uninstall then what should I do ??

Comment: If you are not using it and it is not required by other installed systems then you can remove it. But the only overhead of installed software that is not used is space on the C drive. It has no other effect on your PC's performance.

Answer (score -1):

If you have installed something by yourself, I guess it would be perfectly OK to uninstall it. But if it's some system software that you have no idea of, I would recommend to google the name and find out if it's safe to remove.